# Trouble with established a remote repository on external hard-drive with Git Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio-2017

Hello and thanks in advance.

I'm not very familiar with git and I want to start using it on my projects on Visual Studio 2017. I searched here on Stack-overflow and other sites ( including the Git Pro book ) for guidance and I still can't figure out how to make a project and set a new remote repository on an external hard-drive.

I opened a new project in Visual-Studio while the "Create new Git repository" is checked, so far so good. Now after writing a simple code ( like "Hello World" for an instance ) I made a clone through the "Team Explorer - Connect" view at Local Git repositories section into an external hard-drive.

Now what I'm asking is how I can use that clone to be a remote repository for other computers, and how to do it because I fail to manage that part so far. In other words, I'm trying to open a new Visual Studio session and fetch the project located at the "Remote" repository on the hard-drive into that session.

Thanks again, Rachel.

Comment: They clone the repository themselves. Git is a distributed source control, each person has a copy. Central repositories everyone connects and checks in to, distributed everyone clones and does pulls and pushes.

Answer (score 0):

Remote repository should be located at the server. Every developer that wants to contribute can clone that repo to their machine and work on the local copy.

If you would like to upload your repository somewhere for free, then you can use [GitHub](https://github.com/)

Other known services that allow to host Git repositories:

- [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/)
- [GitLab](https://about.gitlab.com/)